# change event in cytoscape.js graph

Tags: javascript, angular, cytoscape.js

I used `cytoscape.js` in my project angular.
I want to detect any change in graph(cytoscape.js) with only a event.
Changes can include anything from resizing, changing colors, moving the nodes, and so on.
Is there just one event to detect all of these changes?

Comment: Please share your code and describe your current approach. Cytoscape.js has extensive documentation on events, so please do some research and refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are user input events, collections events, and graph events. There are lots of events. For example, for [collection events](https://js.cytoscape.org/#events/collection-events) you can write an event listener like

`cy.on('add remove move select unselect tapselect tapunselect boxselect box lock', function(ev) { console.log('hey some event happened on cy: ', ev);}`

Then listen for all the events.